# How to run an Android 10 system image built by myself on emulators?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, android-build

I follow the [Android doc](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building) to build an AOSP (Android 10).

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86-eng
m -j32
```

Once building successfully, I use the `emulator` command to test if the built image can run. On my server running CentOS 8 Stream, the emulator can launch successfully and everything looks good.

However, when I try to move the built system image to my MacBook, the emulator only shows a blank screen even after 5 minutes.

I used to build an Android 7 system image (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136194/cannot-launch-android-emulator-using-customized-built-system-images)). All I need to do is to move the `system.img` and `ramdisk.img` to my MacBook's SDK folder. But this does not work for Android 10.

What should I move (e.g., `system.img`, `ramdisk.img`, `vendor.img`, `userdata.img`...) to make the built AOSP running on my Mac's emulators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding more about AOSP build outputs (especially all the `.img`s under `out/target/product/generic_x86`), here is what I did to load the self-built system image on Mac's emulators:

1. Copy `system-qemu.img` to `<android_sdk>/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86` on the MacBook. Then rename `system-qemu.img` to `system.img` (You can delete the original `system.img` or just give it another name).
2. Copy `VerifiedBootParams.textproto` to `<android_sdk>/system-images/android-29/google_apis/x86` on the MacBook. Also remember to delete or rename the original one before copying. I guess it has something to do with `vbmeta.img`, which is used to verify `system.img`. Without this file, your emulators cannot launch because of verification failure. Refer [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/edd03a9d64ec919237da99f7d5ba922c2fc60ebc/README.md) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The LineageOS wiki has [instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/emulator#exporting-for-use-in-android-studioavd) on exporting the compiled emulator images and running them independently in an Android Virtual Device.

They should still work for pure AOSP as well.

Essentially, you can run `mka sdk_addon` to build a .zip file that contains all the necessary images for running the build in an emulator.